# Getting Data between yesterdays date and todays date in MYSQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I run this query to fetch some data

```py
Query = my_cursor.execute("SELECT concat(FORMAT(Sum(RealCash),0))  FROM fantasy.Transaction WHERE (TransactionType=4 AND Status=1) AND DateModified BETWEEN  '2022-06-27 18:30:00' AND  '2022-06-28 18:29:30')
```

Now what i want is to replace the `(BETWEEN  '2022-06-27 18:30:00'` with "Yesterdays Date" and `(AND  '2022-06-28 18:29:30')` with todays date. So that i don't have to change the date everyday, Automatically when i run the code it will give me the data between yesterday and today date
I'm using MYSQL and Python for this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you still want the time part of the dates (`18:30:00`?)

Comment: No i want the data for the whole day for eg the whole data for 27th june

Comment: ```.. AND DateModified >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND DateModified < CURRENT_DATE```

Answer (score 0):

you can get this using time module:

```
import time
now = time.time()
pretty_today = time.ctime(now)
pretty_yesterday = time.ctime(now - 24*60*60)
print(pretty_today)
print(pretty_yesterday)
```

output :

```
Tue Jun 28 11:59:57 2022
Mon Jun 27 11:59:57 2022
```